# Downloading file during p:ajax rowSelect event in p:dataTable

Tags: jsf, primefaces, datatable, download

I want to download a document file by row click on primefaces datatable. I tried to call the action from Bean by using ajax like this:

```
<p:dataTable
            id="docId"
            value="#{testBean.document}"
            var="doc"
            selectionMode="single"
            selection="#{testBean.selectedDoc}"
            >

            <p:ajax event="rowSelect" listener="#{testBean.actionDownload}"/>

            <p:column>
                ...
            </p:column>
                ...
</p:dataTable>
```

But the following code does not execute what I want. The logic of my action is correct. But seems so that the downloading document does not work with ajax Request. There is no reaction and the download does not executed.

```
public String actionDownload() {
    try {
        FacesContext facesContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
        HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) facesContext.getExternalContext().getResponse();

        StringBuffer contentDisposition = new StringBuffer();
        contentDisposition.append("attachment;");
        contentDisposition.append("filename=\"");
        contentDisposition.append(name);
        contentDisposition.append("\"");

        response.reset();
        response.setContentType("application/x-download");

        response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", contentDisposition.toString());
        ServletOutputStream out = response.getOutputStream();
        response.setContentType("application/x-download");
        out.write(output);
        out.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
    FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().responseComplete();
    return null;
}
```

Is there an alternative to download a file by click on Datatable row?

Comment: Is the method `actionDownload()` getting invoked?

Comment: @Selaron: from what I get it is not. Remarkable that OP thinks it is related to downloading and not tries to put just a `system.out.println` in there

Comment: @Selaron: Yes, method actionDownload() is invoked and executed. But nothing happened. I tested the method actionDownload() by calling from commandButton and everything was ok. But calling by Ajax does not bring the same result.

Comment: See there you narrowed down the problem. I thought there would be a duplicate (therefor I did not answer yet and wanted you to narrow down the problem) bit if @BalusC answers there is no need to try to find a duplicate since there with 99,999% certainty is not

Answer (score 3):

You cannot download files with JSF/PrimeFaces Ajax. Make it a non-Ajax request instead.

Replace ajax listener in `<p:ajax>` by a GET request in `oncomplete` something like:

```
<p:ajax event="rowSelect" oncomplete="window.location='#{request.contextPath}/download/#{doc.id}'"/>
```

And replace backing bean method `actionDownload()` by a plain vanilla Servlet something like:

```
@WebServlet("/download/*")
public class Download extends HttpServlet {

    @Inject
    private DocumentService service;

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        Document document = service.find(Long.valueOf(request.getPathInfo().substring(1)));
        response.setContentType(getServletContext().getMimeType(document.getFileName()));
        response.setContentLength(document.getContent().length);
        response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=\"" + URLEncoder.encode(document.getFileName(), "UTF-8") + "\"");
        response.getOutputStream().write(document.getContent());
    }

}
```